# How can I create a database using SQLite3 in python 3 for mac?

Tags: sqlite, python-3.x

So far this is the code I have and I keep getting an error stating:
 "sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error"

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect("DatabaseName.sql")

cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE Contacts (Fname TEXT,
Lname TEXT, Phone INTEGER,)""")

Fname = input("Enter first name: ")
Lname = input("Enter last name: ")
Phone = input("Enter telephone number(no dashes or spaces): ")
Phone = int(Phone)


cur.execute("""INSERT INTO Contacts (Fname, Lname, Phone, joined_club)
VALUES (?,?,?)""", (Fname,Lname,Phone))

con.commit()

cur.close()
con.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an extra comma in your create statement, before the close paren. It should be:

```
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE Contacts (Fname TEXT,
Lname TEXT, Phone INTEGER)""")
```

Later on, you have an extra parameter, `joined_club`, in your `INSERT` statement. It should be:

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO Contacts (Fname, Lname, Phone)
VALUES (?,?,?)""", (Fname,Lname,Phone))
```